# 'new' and 'delete' is not as scalable as intel thread building block scalable_malloc/free

Tags: parallel-processing

To be clear, this is not an advertisement for tbb library. just something that I found recently that quite suprised me.

I did a litte google on heap contention. and it seems that after glibc 2.3. 'new' and 'delete' had been improved to support multiprocessors very well.  my glibc is 2.5. and for following very simple code.

```
tbb::tick_count t1 = tbb::tick_count::now();

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 100000; ++i)
    {
        char * str = new char [100];
        delete str;
    }
tbb::tick_count t2 = tbb::tick_count::now();
std::cout << "process time = " << (t2 - t1).seconds() << std::endl;
```

I got a Linux box with 16 CPU cores. and I started 1 and 8 threads, respectively to run above code. the first thing that supprised me is that the process time is less while there were 8 threads running. this made no sense to me. how is this even possible?

Other test I did is that instead of above simple code, each thread runs a quite complex algorithm, during the algorithm, there is quite a lot of new and delete too. and while the thread number increased from 1 to 8, the processing time almost increased by 100%.

You may ask how did I know that it's 'new' and 'delete' caused the time increasing, it's because after I replaced 'new' and 'delete' with tbb's scalable_malloc/free, the processing time only increased by around 5% when thread number was increased from 1 to 8.

here is one more mystery to me, why 'new' and 'delete' didn't scale as well as in previous simple code.

another mystery is that if I added the previous simple code at the front of the algorithm that each thread runs. then there was no time increasing at all while I increased thread number from 1 to 8.

I was so suprised by my test. Could anyone please give an explanation for my test results? many thanks here.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a mystery at all. It is well known that memory allocation in multi-threaded applications suffers increasing thread blocking time (in particular, this happens for sleeping threads in the kernel TASK_UNINTERRUPTIBLE state on Linux). And allocation of memory from the heap can quickly become a bottleneck, since the standard allocator deals with multiple allocation request from several threads by serializing the requests. These are the main reasons for the degraded performances you are experiencing. Of course, this in turn leads to the implementation of efficient allocators. You cited the TBB one, but there are other freely available alternatives.

See, for instance, the [ThreadAlloc](http://www.garret.ru/sal.html) library which, as stated by his author, "Provides about 10 times benefit in performance comparing with standard allocator at SMP platforms for multithreaded application intensivelly using dynamic memory allocation".

Another option is [Hoard](http://www.hoard.org/).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments, could you please tell me where I can find an artical that explainning this in detail?   yet there is still a mystery part which is that "if I call 'new' and 'delete' in a tight loop before starting running the algorithm, the overhead of 'new' and 'delete' is gone." is there an explannation for this?

Comment: I read the documentation of ThreadAlloc library, the mystery part to me is that mutex is held for the reason that makes multi-thread running slow.  but I really doubt that, because if mutex is the reason, then running code like "for (size_t i = 0; i < 10000000;++i) char * p = new char[100]; delete p;" in multiple threads on multi-processor platform would be definitely solwer, but it's actually faster. another puzzle to me, in any case, it should be as fast, how come it's even faster.

Comment: by the way, I tested Hoard, and I am really not doing advertisement for tbb. but from the results, tbb is about twice ~ four times faster than Hoard.

Comment: Here you are a couple of articles, to get you started: http://people.cs.vt.edu/~scschnei/papers/ismm06.pdf and http://www.cs.umass.edu/%7Eemery/hoard/asplos2000.pdf

Comment: The most probable reason why you do not see overhead if running your sample code before the algorithm, is that, overall, the overhead incurred at the beginning is compensated by the subsequent running of the algorithm. Instead, if you run first the algorithm, and then your sample code, there is no way to recover anything once the algorithm is done. In practice, the algorithm may, in some sense, mask the overhead.

Comment: TBB is a commercial implementation, and I have very little doubts that it will not produce the same or better performances on intel processors indeed.

Comment: I did not read how exactly all of these allocators are implemented, so I can not be of help in this case.